# Issue in correlated subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below query i have 2 table product and product status in product table i have productid,productname and in productstatus table i have locationid,productid,currentstock,unitprice,statu.I want to write a correlated query to get the productname,currentstock,locationid.i tried but it display all product name with no currentstock.I can't able to get product based on date and locationid.Pls help me to do this.

Correlated subquery

```
SELECT p.ProductID,
       p.ProductName,
       (SELECT CurrentStock
        FROM   ProductStatus PS
        WHERE  PS.ProductID =p.ProductID
               AND PS.LocationID = 1
               AND PS.Statu = '2014-10-14')
FROM   Product P
```

Table structure and data

```
CREATE TABLE #Product
  (productid   INT,productname VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #Product
VALUES      (1,'biscuit'),
            (2,'soap'),
            (3,'flower')

CREATE TABLE #Productstatus
  (
     locationid   INT,
     productid    INT,
     currentstock INT,
     unitprice    INT,
     statu        DATE
  )

INSERT INTO #Productstatus
VALUES      (1,1,200,10,'2014-10-14'),
            (1,2,300,10,'2014-11-16'),
            (2,3,200,10,'2014-12-12')
```

Comment: Please do not use inline subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

using correlated subquery.

```
SELECT p.ProductID,
       p.ProductName,
       (SELECT CurrentStock
        FROM   #Productstatus PS
        WHERE  PS.ProductID =p.ProductID
               AND PS.LocationID = 1
               AND PS.Statu = '2014-10-14'
               and PS.productid=p.productid) CurrentStock
FROM   #Product P
```

Comment: it is not working it displys all product with no currentstock .Where condition is not working

Comment: @Developer Add some data of those two tables in the question then only i can check y its not working!!

Comment: I have added the data i am looking for correlated query pls help me to rectify the error

Comment: @Developer problem is PS.Statu = '2014-10-10' there is no such data for any product in Productstatus table thats y u are getting null values. Now i changed to a existing date ('2014-10-14'). check now

Comment: what is #?it display all product but i mentioned locationid =1 so only one product should display but it displays 3 products

Comment: @Developer This is correlated subquery unless u put some filter on the outer query it going tot return you all the rows from the outer query. For ur problem u should go for join then u will get ur expected output which will return only one row (ie) productId which has locationid=1 and specified date

Comment: @Developer If you prefix # before tablename then it will be created as temporary table and it will automatically dropped when session is closed

Answer (score 0):

Try and let me know... also specify output what you want, so it will easy to prepare query for you.

```
-- Data only with Stock       
SELECT p.PRODUCTID, p.PRODUCTNAME, ps.LOCATIONID,ps.CURRENTSTOCK,ps.UNITPRICE
FROM 
PRODUCT p INNER JOIN PRODUCTSTATUS ps
ON p.PRODUCTID = ps.PRODUCTID
WHERE ps.STAT ='2014-10-14'


-- Data with /without Stock       
SELECT p.PRODUCTID, p.PRODUCTNAME, ps.LOCATIONID,ps.CURRENTSTOCK,ps.UNITPRICE
FROM 
PRODUCT p LEFT JOIN PRODUCTSTATUS ps
ON p.PRODUCTID = ps.PRODUCTID
```